# Trivial second homology group

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^3$ be a an open bounded set.
Let us consider the following statement:

> every closed surface in $\Omega$ is the boundary of a suitable
>   subdomain $D\subset\Omega$.

How is this statement related to Homology or Cohomology theories? I am not at expert at all about algebraic topology, it's a matter of curiosity. I'm sorry if the question does look too much naive.

Comment: By $\mathbb{H}^2(\Omega)$, do you mean the second cohomology group? Singular? deRham? Something else entirely? And if you meant cohomology, what coefficients? If you'd written a subscript of $2$, this would be nearly the definition.

Comment: Sorry, unfortunately I just studied the De Rham Cohomology, so I didn't know the notation for homology. Is it fine now?

Comment: I don't know whether it's fine: *you're* the one with the question. Since there are about 200 different kinds of homology theory, you'll also have to tell us which one, and what coefficients you're using. It sure *looks* as if this is pretty much straight from the definition of singular homology, although I don't know what "domain" means in your context.

Comment: Singular homology with integer coefficients

Comment: It is a question of algebraic topology, not algebraic geometry

Answer (score 2):

This follows from standard forklore in differential topology (maybe due to Thom or Poincare??):

Let $M^n$ be a smooth orientable $n$-manifold, then any homology class of codimension 1 or 2, that is, an element in $H_{n-1}(M^n)$ or $H_{n-2}(M^n)$, can be represented by the fundamental class of a submanifold.

Comment: Poincare used this for codimension 1 in one of his proofs of duality.  But his argument for it was terrible,and this is one reason he shifted from (something vaguely like) singular homology to simplicial.